# 301 Redirect for localhost/*/path to localhost/*/path/

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Similar questions have been asked before but it isn't clear!

I have a folder structures like these:

```
http://example.com/category1/subcat1/path1
http://example.com/category2/subcat2/path2
http://example.com/category3/subcat3/path3
```

I want to redirect them to the following respectively:

```
http://example.com/category1/subcat1/stuff1
http://example.com/category2/subcat2/stuff2
http://example.com/category3/subcat3/stuff3
```

Notice: I need any request to example.com/path to redirect to example.com/path/ if example.com/path doesn't exist!

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/
RewriteRule ^path1/$ path1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^path1/(.*)$ path1 [R=301,L]
```

Pls, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the rewrite base. It's a file-path and not a URL-path so you'll end up getting redirected to `http://example.com/var/www/path1`.

For the trailing slash, you want:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^path1$ /path1/ [R=301,L]
```

For the rest:

```
RewriteRule ^category1/subcat1/path1$ /category1/subcat1/stuff1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category2/subcat2/path2$ /category2/subcat2/stuff2 [R=301,L]
```

etc.

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I got this: Not Found The requested URL /blog was not found on this server." for the "RewriteRule ^path1$ /path1/ [R=301,L]".

Comment: @Ema4rl what does **blog** have anything to do with **path1**?

Comment: I need something like: localhost/blog to redirect to localhost/blog/ if /blog doesn't exist. And /blog can be anything. It should also work  for localhost/anything -> localhost/anything/ Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ema4rl That was not made clear **at all** from your question. see the additional edit

Comment: Pls, try to understand the **title**. I really need this @ _Jon_ _Lin_ .

Comment: I don't know why the edit isn't working cause it looks like what I need. Do I have to restart my server? (Iv'e never come across this problem in online servers. Do I have to make some edits in httpd.conf?).

Comment: @Ema4rl you don't need to restart anything if it's in the htaccess file in your document root